# Permission error ruby on rails passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can fix the below error by doing chmod -R 777 current (as root). But obviously that is not the way to fix it. The current folder is owned by user cmuench:cmuench. Apache user and group is www-data

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /var/www/sites/blastoserver.com/current/public/stylesheets/.permissions_check.68324750.30686.12319):
    5:  <script type="text/javascript">
    6:  function IS(){}
    7:  </script>
    8:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag ['autocomplete.css', 'datepicker.css', 'web.css', 'common.css', 'home.css', 'course.css', 'admin.css'], :cache => true %>
    9:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag [@current_client.name.downcase + '/' + @current_client.name.downcase + '.css'], :cache => false %>
    10:   <%= javascript_include_tag ['jquery.js', 'class.js', 'jquery.extensions.js','nested_form.js','jquery.tablednd.js','jquery.autocomplete.js', 'date.js', 'datepicker.js', 'rails.js', 'common.js', 'navigation.js', 'patient_autocomplete.js', 'courses/course_request.js', 'course_steps/sort_course_steps.js', 'course_steps/next_step.js', 'enrollments/complete_course.js', 'flowplayer/flowplayer.js', 'flowplayer/playlist.js', 'course_steps/video.js', 'course_steps/presentation.js', 'highcharts.js', 'reports/course_assignment.js', 'reports/courses_allocated.js', 'reports/pie_chart.js'], :cache => true %>
    11:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___225745557_81615570__517096065'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from the [passenger user guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) (the apache version, but the nginx one should be the same):

> Phusion Passenger will by default run the web application as the owner
>   of the file config/environment.rb (for Rails apps) or config.ru (for
>   Rack apps)

You can override this by setting the `PassengerUser` directive in either the global configuration file, a virtualhost, a `<Directory>` block or a `<Location>` block.

To expand a little bit, I'd only do a `chown -R cmuench:cmuench *`, which should be enough. Double check the permissions of the `public/stylesheets` folder, as it looks like the error comes from here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was the stylesheets and javascript directories not being writable by web server. I had to chmod 777 those folders. Is this the best approach?

Comment: @Chris Not really, if you do this, any user of the system will be able to erase these directories, or worse, serve any javascript to your users. Who owns `config/environment.rb` and `config.ru`?

Comment: If you do `ps aux | grep /var/www/sites/blastoserver.com/current` on your server, you should be able to know who runs your server process (it's in the leftmost columns for me).

Comment: looks like nobody...

cmuench   1138  0.0  0.1   3376   752 pts/0    S+   12:00   0:00 grep --color=auto /var/www/sites/blastoserver.com/current
nobody   30686  0.1  8.1  55800 41724 ?        Sl   09:09   0:19 Rack: /var/www/sites/blastoserver.com/current

Comment: Check the permissions of the `config.ru` file. If it's owned by `cmuench`, you could try to force the user in your apache conf like this: `PassengerUser cmuench`.

Comment: Ok I will try that, I am also trying to reset up and make sure I create the cmuench user BEFORE installing passenger.

Comment: When I reset it up and created user BEFORE installing passenger it worked great! Thanks you

Comment: @Chris no problem, that's what StackOverflow is for ;-)